# R: transforming long time stamps into wide durations

Tags: r

I have data that is long and is a series of time stamps with a delineator of |. There are multiple rows for potential start times (rows with start1, start2, start 3), but only one row for an end time (row with end). My goal is to get durations at the end of the transformation (See description in #2). My dates are formatted as POSIXct.

Data:

```
ID | events | datetime 
ID_1 | start1 | 2015-10-02 19:46:00 EDT
ID_1 | start2 | 2015-10-02 19:46:00 EDT
ID_1 | end | 2015-10-02 22:46:00 EDT
ID_2 | start1 | 2015-10-02 19:46:00 EDT
ID_2 | start2 | 2015-10-02 19:46:00 EDT
ID_2 | start3 | 2015-10-02 19:46:00 EDT
ID_2 | start4 | 2015-10-02 19:46:00 EDT
ID_2 | end | 2015-10-02 22:46:00 EDT
```

Desired end state:

```
ID | event | start datetime | end datetime | duration | datetime  
ID_1 | start2-end | 2015-10-02 19:46:00 EDT | 2015-10-02 22:46:00 EDT | 180 minutes | 2015-10-02
ID_2 | start4-end | 2015-10-02 19:46:00 EDT | 2015-10-02 22:46:00 EDT | 180 minutes | 2015-10-02
```

1. I want to transform this to be a wide dataset. I am not sure how to do this. If there was a way to skip to #3 and create durations at this point, I would do that.

`ID | event | start datetime | end datetime | duration | datetime
ID_1 | start2-end | 2015-10-02 19:46:00 EDT | 2015-10-02 22:46:00 EDT | 180 minutes | 2015-10-02
ID_2 | start4-end | 2015-10-02 19:46:00 EDT | 2015-10-02 22:46:00 EDT | 180 minutes | 2015-10-02`

2. Ultimately, I hope to use the lubridate package and use that to calculate durations (likely in terms of minutes/seconds).

I welcome any insights and am **currently seeking some R mentoring**. Thank you.

EDIT: I initially had some issues with formatting a variable as POSIXct. With @Phann's guidance, I was able to do this with `datetime2 <- as.POSIXct(as.character(data$datetime), format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")`

Comment: Can you add the desired end (“wide”) state to the question? It’s not clear to me from the input what goes together.

Comment: Added. Thank you for following-up.

Comment: Could it be the case that your (time) data is read in as factors? That could easily happen with ``read.table`` if not the option ``stringsAsFactors = F`` is set. Check it e.g. with ``sapply(myDF, class)``.

Comment: Thank you. It is indeed being read in as a factor. My problem is that I cannot seem to figure out how to convert it to a time factor using POSIXct or lt. I thought using the anytime package would resolve this given that it doesn't require a format string, but the command `new_variable <- anytime(datetime)` doesn't seem to do anything and the new variable remains a factor.

Comment: Convert it to a character first. You can do that as one-liner: ``as.POSIXct(as.character(data$time), ......))``. Or you do it when the data is read. The usual read functions have the option ``stringsAsFactors`` for that issue. Btw: be careful when converting factors to numeric ... which may lead to undesired results. But to character there should not be any problem.

Comment: Thank you! It is now POSIXct: `datetime2 <- as.POSIXct(as.character(dataset$datetime), format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")`